# How to use search REST api to get custom managed property data for anonymous user

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, search-api

i am trying build a public portal with anonymous access and i am trying to read some content from custom managed property using search REST api in sharepoint 2013. 
I have tried to enable all possible attributes of the managed prop. Like searchable,queryable,safe etc. also i am including queryparametertemplate in my REST api search query. But still i am not able to retrieve the managed prop. For an anonymous user. 
The same query returns the value if i am logged in.

Comment: I got the answer from Microsoft support check this out: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/16c80387-d3fa-458f-8bd9-7aec28794c8d/how-to-use-search-rest-api-to-get-custom-managed-property-data-for-anonymous-user?forum=sharepointsearch#57e315d9-5ffa-44f3-8644-652986078faa

Answer (score 0):

I got the perfect answer from MSDN forums, please check this out: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/16c80387-d3fa-458f-8bd9-7aec28794c8d/how-to-use-search-rest-api-to-get-custom-managed-property-data-for-anonymous-user?forum=sharepointsearch#57e315d9-5ffa-44f3-8644-652986078faa

Comment: Please add details from that answer here. The answer will not be helpf to future readea if the link breaks, as it is written now!